# Recommended Java frameworks for Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web-frameworks

I'm new to google appengine and java webprogramming (jsp/servlets/frameworks) (not to webprogramming or java).  I was wondering if appengine supported java frameworks and, if so,  which of them are recomandable?  Are there any frameworks that support authentication?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

A Google employee linked to the following information on a [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/msg/4ee376d9daf9b796):

> While we do not support the entirety of the Java EE specification, many of its individual components are supported. These include:
>
> - Java Data Objects (JDO) -- notes
> - Java Persistence API (JPA) -- notes
> - Java Server Faces (JSF) 1.1 - 2.0
> - Java Server Pages (JSP) + JSTL
> - Java Servlet API 2.4 -- notes
> - JavaBeans™ Activation Framework (JAF)
> - Java Architecture for XML Binding (JAXB)
> - Java API for XML Web Services (JAX-WS)
> - JavaMail -- notes
> - XML processing APIs including DOM, SAX, and XSLT

Answer (score 2):

[Gaelyk](http://gaelyk.appspot.com/) is a framework designed specifically to support applications written for the GAE. However it's not a Java framework, it's a Groovy framework. However, Groovy the language is almost a strict superset of Java, so if you know Java, you should find it very easy to learn. In fact, it's quite likely that if you use Gaelyk you can write most/all of your code in Java (though I wouldn't recommend this), because most Groovy libraries/framework work with either Groovy or Java code.

The [Groovy Web Console](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/) is built using Gaelyk. It's an app that allows you to run Groovy code in a webpage.

Answer (score 2):

[Jello-framework](http://jello-framework.com) is a new Java framework for Google App Engine.
According to it's site it is an End-to-End Java framework including comprehensive Data Authorization model, a powerful RESTful engine, and out-of-the-box UI views.